# wrapbootstrap Theme with AngularJS Issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Wrapbootstrap Theme ACE Template https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR with AngularJS but it doesn't work fine; The sidebar and settings not works correctly; If i removed AngularJS, it Works fine; I think the Problem is related to the theme JavaScript files are loaded and executed before Angular load and render the partials; I want to know how to load Theme Scripts(two scripts ace-elements.js, ace.js) and execute them after the Angular finish his work;[image]

Comment: any feedback as soon as possible

Comment: Have u tried to wrap angular js files in head?

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed my issue, based on a clue you said.  I moved the two (ace-elements and ace) javescript files to the end, after angular did all it's thing and suddenly the menu toggle button which was working on a PC but not on a mobile device worked!